# $_GET['title'] in Wordpress

Tags: php, terms, api

I work on a site developed a few years ago by someone else. An intranet had been developed on this site. A page of this intranet had to list elements does not work.

Here are the first lines, I think the problem comes from there :

```
<?php
    require_once('init.php');
    require('header.php');
    $product = get_term_by('slug', $_GET['title'], 'product');
?>
```

"*$_GET['title']*" steal empty, and I have never seen the use of $_GET in Wordpress...

On this page, the loop is working well, but I have to use term object to display term title for example.

Comment: Try http://domain.com/this-page-slug?title=product-slug and see if that works.

Comment: @MikeNGarrett actually it's domain.com/intranet/product/product1.  domain.com/product?title=product1 doesn't work.

Comment: I'm not sure how to resolve this given the information. Your question doesn't contain an actual question. What are you trying to do? :-)

Comment: I try to display the title of the page, but it's an intranet (the intranet folder is in the root server). Actualy, I have an error, because $_GET['title'] doesn't work, it steel empty. I do not know if you know what I mean ?

Comment: It sounds like you have a server configuration problem to me.

Comment: I try to change my PHP version (try 7, 5.6, 5.4), nothing change...